# what should i do to make this SQL query work?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT s.Name, (
COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM pruefen p WHERE p.MatrNr = s.MatrNr AND p.Note < 5) / 
COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM pruefen p WHERE p.MatrNr = s.MatrNr)
) as Anteil FROM Studenten s

ORDER BY Anteil DESC, s.Name ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What's not working, what's your schema, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i was able to fix it throughout your comments! :) i was just overwhelmed with the details ! 
my final solution was 

SELECT s.Name, (
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pruefen p WHERE p.MatrNr = s.MatrNr AND p.Note < 5) / 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pruefen p WHERE p.MatrNr = s.MatrNr)
) as Anteil FROM Studenten s

ORDER BY Anteil DESC, s.Name ASC
LIMIT 10;

and it worked

Comment: Great that you solved your problem, but... it doesn't belong in a comment (extremely difficult to read unformatted code in a comment). You can either delete the question (since you got past your error) or post a proper answer (but with all needed details, not just posting code in an answer). Further: without specific details in your question, there's no actual question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure this query will work; meaning that it won't return an error but I'm not certain if it will return correct result as what you intended:

```
SELECT s.Name, 
       SUM(p.Note=5)/COUNT(*) as Anteil 
FROM Studenten s
JOIN pruefen p ON p.MatrNr = s.MatrNr 
GROUP BY s.Name
ORDER BY Anteil DESC, s.Name ASC;
```

If this doesn't return the result you're looking for, [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72890787/edit) with data samples and expected output.

Comment: Does mysql treat that as integer division? (if so, it will nearly always return 0)  You might also want to use a left join, just incase there are no ro s to join on, and account for that with `NULLIF(COUNT(p. MatrNr), 0)`

Comment: this way of writing the query is much more efficient than my solution! 
an endless thanks for you people :))